# QProcess fails with Qt 5.10.1 and Windows 10

Tags: qt, qprocess

I recently compiled Qt 5.10.1 statically (mingw32) and the routine below now fails to work.  I modified the code to include the full path for windows cmd "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" but that still doesn't work. Attempted with Windows 7 & 10. The code below works fine with Qt 5.6. Its job is to open a Windows terminal. Similar code to open a console in macOS and Linux works.

NOTE:  This behavior is a bug introduced in Qt 5.8 see:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57687

```
    QString commstr = adbdir+"cpath.bat";
    QFile file(commstr);

        if(!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly |
                      QFile::Text))
        {
            logfile("error creating cpath.bat!");
            QMessageBox::critical(this,"","Error creating bat file!");
            return;
        }

        QTextStream out(&file);
        out  << "set PATH=%PATH%;"+QDir::currentPath()+";"<< endl;

        file.flush();
        file.close();

        cstring = "cmd /k " +QDir::currentPath()+"/cpath.bat";
        QProcess::startDetached(cstring);
```

Comment: Which compiler?

Comment: Question edited to show mingw32.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: This behavior with startDetached is a Windows-specific Qt bug introduced in Qt 5.8. The workaround is referenced at:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57687

```
   QProcess p;
        p.setProgram("cmd.exe");
        p.setArguments({"/k", QDir::currentPath()+"/cpath.bat"});
        p.setCreateProcessArgumentsModifier([] ( 
    QProcess::CreateProcessArguments
        *args) {
                args->flags &= ~CREATE_NO_WINDOW;
            });
        p.startDetached();
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way in Qt 5.10 is to pass arguments to QProcess program, so when you want to run `cmd /k cpath.bat` then the program is `cmd` and the arguments are `/k xyz.bat` . Also according to bug report [QTBUG-64662](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-64662), Qt does start the process starts but to make it appear, that might be related to win32 API, so using `QProcess::setCreateProcessArgumentsModifier` could be used to show the shell as describer in [QProcess Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#CreateProcessArgumentModifier-typedef).
So in your case:

```
#include "Windows.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QProcess process;
    QString program = "cmd.exe";
    QStringList arguments = QStringList() << "/K" << QDir::currentPath()+"/cpath.bat";
    process->setCreateProcessArgumentsModifier([] (QProcess::CreateProcessArguments *args)
    {
        args->flags |= CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;
        args->startupInfo->dwFlags &= ~STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    });
    process.start(program, arguments);
    process.waitForStarted();
    return app.exec();
}
```

---

And in order to create detached process, you can inherit QProcess and detach it after it starts, like this:

```
#include <QProcess>
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDir>
#include "Windows.h"

class QDetachableProcess
        : public QProcess {
public:
    QDetachableProcess(QObject *parent = 0)
        : QProcess(parent) {
    }
    void detach() {
       waitForStarted();
       setProcessState(QProcess::NotRunning);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QDetachableProcess process;
    QString program = "cmd.exe";
    QStringList arguments = QStringList() << "/K" << QDir::currentPath()+"/cpath.bat";
    process.setCreateProcessArgumentsModifier(
                [](QProcess::CreateProcessArguments *args) {
        args->flags |= CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;
        args->startupInfo->dwFlags &=~ STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    });
    process.start(program, arguments);
    process.detach();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work.  I used your code as shown, but no terminal.  Qprocess works otherwise, so it must be an issue with startDetached?

Comment: Question edited to add the fact that similar code for macOS and Linux works.  It's only Windows (10/7) at issue.

Comment: @Alan That only how `cmd.exe` (shell) behaves .. it does start in background and execute your command without you seeing an interactive shell. But in order to keep the shell running you need some modifications as updated the answer.

Comment: @Alan, you could test any other program with previous answer code like `notepad.exe` ... it works as needed. as I mentioned `cmd.exe` is different depending on your local dev-env settings, the default is that cmd.exe starts background shell not interactive shell.

Comment: Substituting notepad does work, thanks for the test and example code. With Qt 5.6  and previous 5.x Qts passing the /k argument sufficed to keep the cmd shell open.  My code as posted is a function assigned to a button. Very simple, in use for over two years.  Still works with 5.6, I just recompiled and tested it.

Comment: @Alan, with the updated answer `cmd.exe` works with with separate shell. I explained in previous comment.