# execute batch-file with qt as a new process

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, batch-file, qprocess

I'm trying to execute a batch file.

This code should start `cmd.exe` in a detached process and execute `deleteme.bat`. The return value of `exec->startDetached` is true but the batch file is not executed.

Am I doing something wrong?

Here's my code:

```
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "/C deleteme.bat";
QProcess * exec = new QProcess();
exec->startDetached("cmd.exe", arguments);
```

Comment: How are you sure it does not run?

Comment: the file should delete itself (del deleteme.bat). if i execute it directly it works. but it does not work with these lines of code. @eyllanesc

Comment: You could show the content of the .bat. Also, the .bat is on the side of the .exe ?, if it is not tested by placing the fullpath.

Comment: the bat file consists of only one row (del deleteme.bat) to the check if it is working. and it is in the same directory as the exe.

Comment: try with `del /path/of/deleteme.bat`

Comment: also didn't work.

Comment: Try with `/C` and `deleteme.bat` as separate arguments -- e.g. `arguments << "/C" << "deleteme.bat";` .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QProcess fails with Qt 5.10.1 and Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49355396/qprocess-fails-with-qt-5-10-1-and-windows-10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working example with `QProcess` (the test `.bat` file's path is `E:\deleteme.bat`):

```
QProcess process;
process.setProgram( "cmd.exe" );
process.setArguments( { "/C", R"(E:\deleteme.bat)" } );
process.setWorkingDirectory( R"(E:\)" );
process.setStandardOutputFile( QProcess::nullDevice() );
process.setStandardErrorFile( QProcess::nullDevice() );
process.startDetached();
```

Here's the `deleteme.bat` file that self-deletes itself:

```
DEL "%~f0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by myself.

```
STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(STARTUPINFO) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

wchar_t cmdline[] = L"cmd.exe /C <batch-file>";

if (!CreateProcess(NULL, cmdline, NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,
    NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
```

this also creates a detached process.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly answering the question as you stated it (you were asking about `QProcess`) but the simplest way to run BAT file in console on Windows is using this line:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(batFilePath));
```

Note that you might also need to set the working directory (typically to the parent dir of the BAT file) with `QDir::setCurrent(workDir)` before running this. You may also need to revert the working dir back after execution of this line. But it depends on your use case.